# How to submit in php inside of an If

Tags: javascript, php, post, cookies, submit

I am completely new to php but I have to add some contribution to an existing project.

I have a page with two buttons. When clicking on one of the buttons, the php code runs. Depending on which button was pressed, something gets written to a database, but only if certain cookie isn't present.

```
 <form name="input" action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="answer" value="No" hidden="true"/>
   <input type="image" name="answer" src="img/nein.png" value="No" />
 </form>


<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['voteCookie'])) {
   //write something to database
}
else {
   //error
}
?>
```

Now I want to make a result page which shows something depending on the presence of the cookie.

So after

```
//write someting to database
```

I want to call a submit to another page using post to submit a string with "ACK".

and after

```
//error
```

I want to call a submit to another page using post to submit a string with "NACK".

How can I do this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want to `POST` to another page, you have to use `curl`. Are you sure you can't use a redirect and a URL parameter, instead of `POST`?

Comment: Do you want to submit the form.? Will passing the `ACK` or `NACK` via url solve your problem.?

Comment: You mean to redirect to another page and adding the value to the end with ?result=ACK? Hm this sounds much simpler. Can I do this  using  header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;  ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form name="input" action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="answer" value="No" hidden="true"/>
   <input type="image" name="answer" src="img/nein.png" value="No" />
   <input type="image" name="answer2" src="img/nein.png" value="clickme" />
 </form>


if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
    //do work
}
else if(isset($_POST['answer2'])){
   //do other work
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't quite understand. How does this help me to submit something to another page?

Comment: to submit form in another page use action="another_page.php". also if you want to pass parameter from one page to another use $_SESSION[''] super global. put parameter in one page in the session and take this parameter with same name from another page

Comment: also if you want to redirect from one submitted page to another you can use header('Location: another_page.php').

Comment: In the future, it's best to include explanation in your answer itself.